# In swiftUI TextField ,can we have some property similar to textfield.text in case of UIkit's TextField without mantaining a state var?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am newly shifting to SwiftUI from UIkit , and in UIkit if we have to use a TextField then we could use a delegate method shouldChangeCharacterIn(textfield:UITextField) and access text from textffield.text, for accessing text value of textfield .But in SwiftUI's TextField we have to pass a State variable for accessing value .

And in my app , i will have a lot of TextField and i dont want to mantain this much state variables .

Is there any way i can get UIkit like behavior in SwiftUI's Textfield ?

And also in case of button action ,we can use a func (sender:UIButton) in case of UIkit but in case of SwiftUI we did not get a object of sender ,Is there any way i can achive similar thing in SwiftUI func ?

Comment: No you cant, you can create a `config` file and standardize some of the behavior but SwiftUi `View`s are value types not reference types like in UIKit, you should not hold on to them as variables.